# Questions on an 1840's text: Battle at Yamaki Palace 治承四年八月中句右兵衞佐頼朝公

Tags: translation, meaning, readings, classical-japanese, furigana

I am a bit lost understanding and translating elements of this text from the 1840s, even after persevering for a couple of days.

[image]
[image]

Two versions (with reasonable detail when viewed at actual scale).

My best attempt so far regarding transcription/translation is:

治{ぢ}承{しょう}四{よ}年{ねん}八月中{なか}句{ば}右{う}兵{ひょう}衞{えの}佐{すけ}頼{より}朝{とも}公{こう}源{げん}家{け}再{さい}興{こう}を思{おぼし}召{めし}給{たま}ひ所{しよ}々[／＼]の源{げん}氏{じ}をかたしひ手{て}始{はじめ}に先{まづ}當{とう}國{ごく}の目{もく}代{だい}山{やま}木{き}判{はん}官{がん}兼隆{かねたか}を打{..た}んとて北{ほく}條{じょう}時{とき}政{まさ}を大{たい}将{しょう}と／＼山{やま}木{き}ろ舘{たて}に乱{らん}入{にゅう}大{おう}合戦{かっせん}の圖{づ}

Jishō yonen hachigatsu naka [ba] Uhyōe-no-suke Yoritomo-kō Genke saikō o oboshimeshi tama hi shosho no Genji o katashi hi tehajime ni [mazu] tōgoku no mokudai Yamaki Hangan Kanetaka o [..n?] tote Hōjō Tokimasa o taishō toto Yamaki ro tate ni ran'nyū ō-kassen no zu

Picture of the intrusion at the Yamaki palace during the great battle in the eighth month of the fourth year of the Jishō era [September 1180], when Lord Yoritomo the Assistant Captain of the ‘Right Division of the Middle Palace Guards’ of the Genke thought to restore the Genji [......] during the reign of Yamaki Hangan Kanetaka [......] general and father Hōjō Tokimasa.

Forgive the errors so far, it's a work in progress!

I have confusion or queries with:

Line 1: 句 looks like it is read as ば (ba), despite 句 having readings of く (ku), こう (kō) or すく (suku). Any thoughts?

Line 3: 源, the furigana looks like けん instead of げん. Genke 源家 is an alternative name for Genji. Is it occasional practice to omit the 'dakuten' in earlier texts?

Line 3: unsure of use/meaning of 給 (たま, tama) and ひ (hi).

Line 4: Is it a fair call to say that 所 (しょ, sho) is followed by 々 (with furigana ／＼ kunojiten) rather than a く (ku); thus しょしょ(shosho); “here and there/several places”? If so, I can't make sense of the expression in relation to the rest of the text.

Line 4: Not certain if this is supposed to be かたみ (katami) or かたし (katashi), but presume the latter; “difficult, hard.” Used with ひ (hi)?

Line 5: 手(て)始(はじめ)に (tehajime ni), “at first/at the outset/to begin with?”

Further, I think the 4th character is 先... the furigana seems to suggest a reading of まづ (mazu)/まず, certainly not せん (sen). But what does it mean?—先ず, まず, “first (of all), to start with, about, almost, anyway, well, now, hardly (with neg. verb)”—especially in the context of the preceding characters?

Line 5: 當國 = tōgoku, “a country”?... I can see the two characters used together on some Chinese websites but putting it into online Japanese dictionaries doesn’t get me very far.

Line 5: 目代 (もくだい) = mokudai. Moku = a counter for ‘go’ pieces? Dai = “generation/reign.” Meaning?

Line 7: 打 (...た, ...ta): I can’t make sense of this if the kanji is right!

Line 8: 大将 (たいしょう, Taishō), the furigana しょ in front of the う doesn’t correspond to any reference I have, it looks like one character. Also, the furigana き in Yamaki 山木 (やまき) looks like a za ざ. Again, can’t find any parallels.

Line 8: Is this ろ (ro)? If so, would it attach to the Yamaki (Yamaki-ro), and why?

Line 9: 入(にゅう) looks as if the furigana is truncated to にう omitting the ゅ. Again, assuming the character is correct, is this possible/common for this period?

---

Notes:
Regarding Minamoto Yoritomo’s official appellation *Uhyōe-no-suke*: *Uhyōe* (右兵衛) is composed of the characters for “right,” “soldier/army,” and “defence/protection,” literally “right army defence,” or “right military guards,” and to my knowledge *suke* (佐) can be translated as “Vice-“ or “Assistant Captain.” Yoritomo’s rank within the *Uhyōe-fu* (右兵衛府), the “Right Division of the Middle Palace Guards,” was part of the *Ritsuryō* (律令) system that defined a system of ranks (*kan’i*, 官位) and positions within the government.  The word *Genke* is also used (...*Uhyōe-no-suke Yoritomo-kō Genke*...): the names Taira and Minamoto were known by alternatives, used interchangeably, even though Taira and Minamoto were essentially family names. The Heike and Genke names were normally associated with the Genpei War: Heishi and Heike for the Taira, and Genji and Genke for the Minamoto.

Useful references:
http://hikog.gokenin.com/hiraganagojuonjun.html
https://wakancambridge.files.wordpress.com/2017/05/hentaigana-chart.jpg
http://naruhodo.weebly.com/uploads/9/7/3/4/9734434/kuzushikana.pdf

---

Any observations/suggestions appreciated. Cheers.

[image]

Comment: It'd help us if you told us where you found this image and why you're trying to understand it. Also I dont know where you got that ば from for 句... (same for なか)

Comment: Two notes: (1), this is not consequential as you've substituted the "correct" equivalents to represent the necessary word, but you have some *kanji* transcription errors if keeping faithful to the original text: 承 should be 羕, and 隆 should be 隆. 隆 is a bit difficult to correct due to [Han unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification) issues. (2) If you want to search Japanese words on specifically Japanese websites, you need to use [Shinjitai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinjitai); to find 當國 you need to search 当国 and add a kana, otherwise you'll end up with Chinese results.

Comment: Thanks for these notes. You have me well pegged in terms of preferring to transcribe the characters as accurately as I can (though my inexperience shows). I couldn't find 羕 in Jisho (tried to assemble it using their radicals, it's now obvious why that failed). I had to default to 承, though the expanded search of 承 at http://clioapi.hi.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ships/ZClient/W34/z_srchDo.php gave clear examples of 羕. I admit to having missed the extra stroke in 隆, but your explanation led me back to https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/隆 where their explanation under the Translingual section made perfect sense.

Comment: @droooze, on the issue of 當國, I was uncertain what you meant with "you need to search 当国 and ADD A KANA". I took your advice to check 当.  My thoughts are: 當國 is tōgoku, “this country.” Looking for a logical meaning/trans' of 當 isn’t helpful, however, you note 當 is a variant of 当. The On reading of 当 is tō (トウ); if used as a prefix it means “this (business organisation or place). The On reading of 國/国 is koku (こく). こく becomes ごく, just as it does in 島国, shimaguni (しまぐに) or tōgoku (とうごく), “island country,” a metaphor for Japan; and 東国, tōgoku (とうごく), “eastern country/provinces” etc. That's OK?

Comment: Apologies, I made a mistake - it should be  rather than 羕. Anyway, 当国 is the official form of the characters of both PRC and Japan, so adding a *kana* like the common particles は or の is a quick and dirty way of filtering Japanese-only results from Chinese ones. The more reliable method is to go into Google settings directly and filter results by language. Finally, handwriting recognition apps are more reliable and less tiresome than character lookup using components, and apps for Chinese-language are generally better than those for Japanese as they encompass more character variants.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Questions and Answers

I'll answer your questions in order.

> Line 1: 句 looks like it is read as ば (ba), despite 句 having readings of く (ku), こう (kō) or すく (suku). Any thoughts?

The kanji are used here as a kind of 熟字訓【じゅくじくん】 for the word *nakaba*, commonly spelled in the modern language as 半ば.  Even then, I'd expect to see 中**旬** instead; I wonder if the author is being poetic by using 句 ("verse, stanza, phrase") instead of the similarly shaped 旬 ("ten-day period, portion of a month").

> Line 3: 源, the furigana looks like けん instead of げん. Genke 源家 is an alternative name for Genji. Is it occasional practice to omit the 'dakuten' in earlier texts?

The use of 濁点【だくてん】 was only standardized some time after the end of WWII, with earlier texts apparently using the 〃 and ゜ marks as a kind of optional indicator.  See also [the Japanese Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%BF%81%E7%82%B9).

> Line 3: unsure of use/meaning of 給 (たま, tama) and ひ (hi).

給【たま】ひ is the 連用形【れんようけい】 of the verb 給【たま】ふ, used as a kind of auxiliary to indicate respect for the agent of the main verb.

> Line 4: Is it a fair call to say that 所 (しょ, sho) is followed by 々 (with furigana ／＼ kunojiten) rather than a く (ku); thus しょしょ(shosho); “here and there/several places”?

That's sure what it looks like to me.

> If so, I can't make sense of the expression in relation to the rest of the text.

Presumably, 所々の源氏 would mean "the Genji [households, family members] in various places".

> Line 4: Not certain if this is supposed to be かたみ (katami) or かたし (katashi), but presume the latter; “difficult, hard.” Used with ひ (hi)?

The 崩【くず】し字【じ】 are certainly hard to read.  In this case, I think this isn't *katashi hi*, but rather *katarahi*, the 連用形【れんようけい】 of verb かたらふ, modern 語【かた】らう, "to be telling [continously, repetitively]; to consult with; *[in this context especially]* to make an ally of; etc.".

> Line 5: 手(て)始(はじめ)に (tehajime ni), “at first/at the outset/to begin with?”

Can't think what else this would be.

> Further, I think the 4th character is 先... the furigana seems to suggest a reading of まづ (mazu)/まず, certainly not せん (sen). But what does it mean?—先ず, まず, “first (of all), to start with, about, almost, anyway, well, now, hardly (with neg. verb)”—especially in the context of the preceding characters?

まづ is the historical kana spelling for 先【ま】ず, as you note.  Grammatically, this does make sense here, emphasizing the 手始【てはじ】め that comes just before.  We could just as well swap the word order and say 先ず手始めに.

> Line 5: 當國 = tōgoku, “a country”?... I can see the two characters used together on some Chinese websites but putting it into online Japanese dictionaries doesn’t get me very far.

當 is the 旧字体【きゅうじたい】 for 当, just as 國 is the 旧字体【きゅうじたい】 for 国.  Note also that 国 in the context of pre-Meiji Japan internal geography often referred to a province rather than a country.  So 當國 = 当国 = "the province in question, the aforementioned province", which in this context would be [Izu Province](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Izu_Province), where Yamagi no Munetaka held the post of 目代【もくだい】.

> Line 5: 目代 (もくだい) = mokudai. Moku = a counter for ‘go’ pieces? Dai = “generation/reign.” Meaning?

According to Shogakukan, a 目代【もくだい】 was a government position starting from the late-Heian, essentially serving as a representative or agent of the 国【くに】の守【かみ】.

> Line 7: 打 (...た, ...ta): I can’t make sense of this if the kanji is right!

It's definitely the correct kanji.  打つ = "to strike, to crush, to conquer, to subjugate" etc. etc.  The conjugation here is うたむ, where む is the volitional that became う and then merged with the preceding //a// sound to become the うとう form in modern Japanese.  In certain cases, the む instead becomes ん, such as in the set phrase ～`[未然形]`んとする meaning "about to do X", from ～`[未然形]`むとする.  In the text in the images, 打たんとて or 打たんとし seem like they might fit, as these would be appropriate in expressing the intent of Minamoto no Yoritomo.  See also [the writeup of the battle on the Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%9F%B3%E6%A9%8B%E5%B1%B1%E3%81%AE%E6%88%A6%E3%81%84#%E5%B1%B1%E6%9C%A8%E9%A4%A8%E8%A5%B2%E6%92%83), where the first line of the linked paragraph looks like a modern rendering of part of your same quoted text.

> Line 8: 大将 (たいしょう, Taishō), the furigana しょ in front of the う doesn’t correspond to any reference I have, it looks like one character.

This looks to me like せ.  せ was apparently pronounced as //ɕe// up through at least 1603, as seen [here in the 日葡辞書](https://books.google.com/books?id=TFJAAQAAMAAJ&pg=PP590#v=onepage&q&f=true) where ⟨xe⟩ is the Portuguese spelling of the time for せ, and where [the Portuguese ⟨x⟩ is pronounced as //ʃ//](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_orthography#Letter_names_and_pronunciations).  This is how せう in historical kana orthography came to be pronounced as しょう.  The 将 kanji itself has an historical kana orthography of しやう, but if the writer was only aware of this as the reading //ɕoː//, they might not have differentiated しやう and せう, and thus might have picked the "wrong" one for the furigana.

In fact, we see this same furigana at the very beginning, where 治承 is given the kana ぢ**せ**う instead of the "correct" spelling of ぢ**しよ**う.

> Also, the furigana き in Yamaki 山木 (やまき) looks like a za ざ. Again, can’t find any parallels.

It's a ぎ.  If you zoom in a bit in both images, you can see that the top horizontal stroke is there -- it's just faint.

> Line 8: Is this ろ (ro)? If so, would it attach to the Yamaki (Yamaki-ro), and why?

I believe this is a slightly distorted の.  Referring to your two charts for [hentaigana](https://wakancambridge.files.wordpress.com/2017/05/hentaigana-chart.jpg) and [kuzushi kana](http://naruhodo.weebly.com/uploads/9/7/3/4/9734434/kuzushikana.pdf) seems to reinforce my hunch.  In both charts, the diagonal top-to-left-bottom stroke in the ろ is very pronounced, while it is nearly missing from the character in the text.  Meanwhile, the の in the charts sometimes shows the stroke beginning by poking out a bit above the rest of the character, and this is also the only kana with such a top portion where the tail could reasonably curl so far to the left, as seen in the text.  This also fits grammatically.

> Line 9: 入(にゅう) looks as if the furigana is truncated to にう omitting the ゅ. Again, assuming the character is correct, is this possible/common for this period?

The historical kana for 入 are にふ.  Due to phonetic changes in the language, medial (mid-word) //f// sounds tended to either drift towards //w// or disappear altogether, so the ふ here would have been pronounced as う.  We know that the にふ from 入 was already pronounced as にゅう as early as 1603, as noted [here in the 日葡辞書](https://books.google.com/books?id=TFJAAQAAMAAJ&pg=PP369#v=onepage&f=false) (left-hand column).  So here too, it's possible that the writer spelled based on their own understanding, using the furigana にう, which would also be read as にゅう.

→ Separately, I also note that 舘 is given the furigana たち in the text, not たて as in your draft.  The former reading is more specifically about a *redoubt* or other defensible position, and fits this context a bit better.

### Alternative Rendering

Here's my take on a reading:

> 治{ぢ}承{せう}四{よ}年{ねん}八月‍中{なか}句{ば}
>
> 右{う}兵{ひよう}衞{えの}佐{すけ}頼{より}朝{とも}公{こう}
>
> 源{けん}家{け}再{さい}興{こう}を思{おぼし}召{めし}給{たま}ひ
>
> 所{しよ}々[／＼]の源{げん}氏{じ}をかたらひ
>
> 手{て}始{はじめ}に先{まづ}當{とう}國{ごく}の目{もく}代{だい}
>
> 山{やま}木{き}判{はん}官{ぐわん}兼隆{かねたか}を
>
> 打{うた}んとて北{ほう}條{じよう}時{とき}政{まさ}を
>
> 大{たい}将{せう}とし山{やま}木{ぎ}の館{たち}
>
> に乱{らん}入{にう}大{おう}合戦{かっせん}の圖{づ}

See if the above makes things make more sense for you, and post or comment with any further questions.

Comment: Eirikr, I've been going through your answers methodically (still to finish a few). As is my habit, making copious notes: your answers lead to more research. Can't express my gratitude enough. I'd like to make a few observations / ask a few questions (progressively rolled out). 1. In general, it is often hard to trust your first instincts without good resources; hypotheses about characters etc often appear far-fetched. E.g. with @droooze, I had found quite early the  character in 治 (ぢせう/ぢしょう), but defaulted to 治承 because jisho/wiki/etc (quick 'go-to' online resources) gave me no anchor.

Comment: ... Likewise, an alternative せ in jishō 治 (ぢせう/ぢしょう) and せ in taishō 大将(たいせう / たいしょう) kept me ‘in my box’. Looking at the furigana せ in kassen 合戦 (かっせん), there was an undeniably strong visual link with the furigana せ in 治 and 大将 , but I convinced myself this was a furphy. I defaulted to the しょう (even if it kept needling me) because I simply had no other context/filter. Your reference to “how せう in historical kana orthography came to be pronounced as しょう” is simply out of my league, pointing to an idiosyncratic (almost frightening) historical complexity that is overwhelming to contemplate.

Comment: Regarding the word Jishō (治, ぢせう/ぢしょう) as it is written here (1st and 2nd characters, 1st line), as notes by @droooze bring to light, there is a link between the kanji  and 羕, since  is a variant of the Han character 羕 (“flowing water”); and then  is being used as an equivalent for the kanji 承 (with a stand-alone meaning of “acquiesce”). 治承 (ぢしょう) is the standard form used for the Jishō era name (August 1177—July 1181). That said, I can't find anything to suggest why the character  would be used: what is its link with 承?

Comment: OK, nakaba is commonly spelled 半ば (“middle, half, semi, halfway, partly”). As you say, chūjun, 中旬 (ちゅうじゅん, “middle of a month; second third of a month; 11th to 20th day of a month”) would have been a more expected kanji selection, rather than 中句, read as chūku (ちゅうく, “middle part of the verse”). The attack on Yamaki occurred on the seventeenth of the eighth month (September) 1180, so the reference to the middle of the month is logical. Chūjun 中旬 would have been the perfect choice. I agree this must be poetic licence... So far, I've had no success finding references to 中句 in other prints.

Comment: End of the 5th line: there is the word mokudai (目代, もくだい), which I had trouble finding info' on. You made notes that a mokudai is “an agent or executor of a lord starting from the late Heian period; an on-site official or deputy starting from the Kamakura period; a local administrator in the Edo period.”  Jeffrey Mass (Antiquity and Anachronism in Japanese History) mentions that mokudai can be translated as a governor; more specifically an "acting governor," yet also "deputy governor" and "provisional governor." Most texts refer to Yamaki Hangan Kanetaka as deputy governor of Izu.

Comment: In this print, Kanetaka’s name is written with the expected kanji (山木判官兼隆), however as you’ve noted the furigana indicates the name should be pronounced Yamaki (やまき) Hanguwan (はんぐわん) Kanetaka (かねたか). Here is another example where I did not trust my judgement to write はんぐわん rather than はんがん, given the ぐand わ were not difficult to see. I have never come across ‘Hanguwan’ before, and had trouble searching for the appellation online. Last night I found a Mihashi Tokugen (御橋悳言) book on the Heike Monogatari (平家物語證注中; 八木書店, 2000), where the kanji 判官 have Hanguwan (はんぐわん) written beside them.

Comment: Also, a print by Katsukawa Shun'ei, c. 1794, is titled "The Second Sawamura Sojuro in the Role of Yenya Hanguwan, in the Popular Drama "Chushingura" or the Forty-seven Loyal Ronin" (Accession No.: JP916, The Metropolitan Museum of Art, New York).  Though I knew that Hangan (はんがん) could be written as Hōgan (ほうがん), I have found a reference that indicates はんぐわん is a 'ten' (転, a word with altered pronunciation or meaning) on the website https://kotobank.jp/word/判官-78803: ほうがん【判官】:
〔「はんぐわん」の転。「はんがん」とも〕
①  「じょう（判官）」に同じ。
②  衛府の尉で、検非違使を兼ねるもの。
③  ○ 〔検非違使の尉であったところから〕 源義経の称。

Comment: I am still at a loss concerning the start of the 7th line if 打 is read as うた (instead of だ) and is then followed by the kana んとて. I assumed that 'tote' とて is a separate particle. Your notes about the conjugation etc. have gone a little over my head; is it possible you might be able to re-articulate your thoughts?

Comment: Just wanted to clarify 'Hōjō Tokimasa o taishō toto' (北條時政を大将と／＼) in the text. Hōjō Tokimasa is a general (taishō) and a father (toto), more precisely, a father-in-law to Yoritomo (though father-in-law can be written as shūto, 舅, しゅうと). Toto isn't being used metaphorically... it's as basic as that? P.S. thanks for picking up silly errors like me typing ほく instead of ほう for hō in hōjō. P.P.S. don't type in "father-in-law in japanese" in google, it seems like there is a whole pornographic genre out there!!!

Comment: @musha, there's too much here to reply in the comments, so I'll update my answer.  However, I'm short on time for the next few days, so apologies ahead of time for making you wait.